# Another concept of centrality

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, definition

Many [centrality measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Characterization_by_walk_structure) count walks of different types going through or starting/ending at a given vertex.

I wonder if the following concept of centrality in directed graphs which reflects a somehow geometric aspect of centrality (i.e. being *central*) has been considered, defined, and under which  name. The following are *my* terms.

> **in-centrality $c_{in}$** of $\nu$ = the length of the shortest shortest path from a
>   root node (in-degree $0$, e.g. a sensory neuron) to the vertex (distance from the "incoming periphery")
>
> **out-centrality $c_{out}$** of $\nu$ = the length of the shortest shortest path from the
>   vertex to a leaf node (out-degree $0$, e.g. a motor neuron) (distance from the "outgoing periphery")

The centrality of a node might be defined as $|c_{in} - c_{out}|$.

For layered graphs with $l$ layers we have trivially $c_{in} + c_{out} = l$ for all vertices.

An interesting characteristic of a graph could be the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ with
$a_{ij}$ the number of nodes with $c_{in} = i$ and $c_{out}=j$.

For a strictly layered graph this matrix would look like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{0} & \text{1} & \dots & l-1 & l \\ \hline
\text{0} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 &a_{l|0} \\ \hline
\text{1} & 0 & 0  & \dots & a_{l-1|1} & 0\\ \hline
\dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
l-1 & 0 & a_{1|l-1} & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
l & a_{0|l} & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

> **Main question**: Has this concept of centrality been defined and investigated before? Under which name? References are welcome.

**Side question and motivation**: I am interested in (an approximation of) this matrix for typical brains (considered as directed graphs). First of all: what is $l$ for typical brains, i.e. the maximal in- and out-centralities?

Comment: When you say "typical brain", is that a technical term, or are you really asking a neurobiology question?

Comment: The question is not really a neurobiology question, but neurobiology is my motivation. "Typical brain" is *not* a technical term, I think of typical human brains, mammal brains, reptile brains, insect brains...

Comment: That makes it a neurobiology question -- the structure of human brains is not something that can be deduced mathematically, but something you need to ask biologists about.

Comment: Sorry, but I do disagree: it's a pure mathematical question (motivated by neurobiology). Of course, you cannot deduce neurobiological facts mathematically, but that's not what I am for (of course not). But you can *describe* neurobiological systems mathematically, can't you?

Comment: Do you agree that this question cannot be answered without the use of facts outside mathematics, namely the structure of human brains? If so then it is not a mathematical question. If you can add enough information to the question to precisely characterize "typical brains" mathematically, such that someone who knows only graph theory and no neurobiology could be able to answer it, then it would be a mathematical question.

Comment: The question for brain structures was supposed to be a *side* question (and admittedly relies on facts outside mathematics). The *main* question was mathematical: Has this concept of centrality been defined before, and under which name? I'll try to make this clearer in my post.

Comment: That is much better. Before, there was literally only one question mark in your post, and it was on the nonmathematical question, so you can see how people would be misled.

Comment: The question mentions a root node and leaves. Is the directed graph in question expected to be a tree? Or at least a DAG (directed acyclic graph)?

Comment: No, it's only expected to be a directed graph: root = in-degree = 0, leaf = out-degree = 0.

Comment: Not all strongly connected directed graphs are tree graphs (though to be strongly connected, they contain a spanning tree). A centrality measure should be calculable regardless of the graph structure whereas with your definition, $c_{in}$ and $c_{out}$ are undefined for a complete graph.

Answer (score 1):

This measure is not defined in complete graphs as @kbau pointed out in the comments. However this is somewhat unfair because complete graphs are I think not the subject of the question

I do see some value in this measure so I'll share some of my observations with the hope that I can give you some insights on this measure. I will also define a slightly different measure with some very nice properties that as far as I know is not currently studied but related to this one.

As far as I know this has not been studied as a centrality concept and I will attempt to explain why:

In my opinion it does not measure centrality. It doesn't really work if distances can be arbitrary since  extremely high distance connections (very uninteresting connections) can both increase and decrease it's centrality. thus a node that is far away from the rest of the network and that is connected to one leaf/sink node can be either very central of very not central, completely based on how far that sink/leaf node is, mostly independent from the rest of the network. Thus I think with weighted edges it doesn't really work.

Defining it with uniform distances works better but then you get problems with situations with more than one root/source and more than one sink/leaf. Why this gives problems is that slightly different graphs have completely different centrality for it's nodes, by just by adding one sink/leaf or one source/root or one arc. In general this is not a good sign because it means your conecpt of centrality is very unstable and hard to build theory on since it can change very easily. It is also very hard to look at general structures for the matrix you are interested in , since tweeking the graph a little completely changes the values. consider adding or substracting a sink/root or source/root.

**However**
with uniform distances it can give some interesting results. especially if we weigh it on the total number of nodes. first of all it has very low computation time since we can only have to find  shortest paths for the node and the sink and source nodes to the node of interest. If we look at the case with one sink and one source we also get a nice measure of how this graph looks. If we calculate  $ \max \frac{|c_{in}−c_{out}|}{|V|}$ we get an idea about how much this graph behaves like a line; and thus the resilience of the graph in respect to the connectivity of the sink and the source. If $\frac{|c_{in}−c_{out}|}{|V|}$ is close to 1 this means that deleting a small number of edges relative to the total number of edges can mean the source and sink are not connected anymore. While if $\frac{|c_{in}−c_{out}|}{|V|}$  is large this connectivity tends to be very resilient. A nice property is that this can be used to compare very different graphs with this property since the measure is scaled.

In a tree (let L denote the number of leafs) then $\frac{|c_{in}−c_{out}| }{|v|-L}$ denotes a similar notion for the most vulnerable leaf. However this is less general and I am pretty sure it can be improved.

In general your  matrix is something else entirely. the matrix tends to have many values in the higher left corner if the graph is resilient and more values in the lower right corner if it is less stable.